# Definition of a root system generated by roots $a$ and $b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, root-systems

In a paper I am looking at, part of a Lemma starts as follows;

Let $R$ be an irreducible root system. Suppose that $a, b \in R$ are two roots with $| b | \geq |a |$, choose $k \in \{ 1, 2, 3 \} $ to satisfy $ |b | = \sqrt{ k } | a | $. Let $ \langle a , b \rangle $ denote the root system generated by $a$ and $b$.

What is meant by $a$ and $b$ generating a root system? I am struggling to find any definition of this.

Comment: I'd suppose it's the smallest subset of $R$ which contains $a$ and $b$ and is a root system in the subspace it spans. Or equivalently, all elements in $R$ which can be written as sums of multiples of $a$ and $b$. Which, further, should be a root system of type $B_2=C_2$ for $k=2$, type $G_2$ for $k=3$, and either $A_2$ or $A_1\times A_1$ for $k=1$.